# Visual Flow - Unable to update record

Tags: case, contact, visual-workflow

I have a Visual Flow with which launches from the Contact records and creates a Case record during the Flow. The case is then successfully assigned to the Contact from which the Flow was launched.Below is the code from the Button:

```
https://cs18.salesforce.com/flow/Complaints_Flow_Contact/301110000008SNsAAM?ContactID={!Contact.Id}
```

I would like to update a custom Email field on the Case record with the existing email from the Contact record. Can anyone help with this. I have tried doing so with a 'Record Update' in the flow but have not been successful.

Comment: what happens? Do you have a result screen and a Fault message screen wired in after the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution - I used a Record Lookup in the Flow instead of using a Record update or Record Create. This looked up the contact email from the Contact Record that the Flow was launched from and inserted it to the new case that has been created during the Flow.- [image]

Answer (score 1):

There could be two possible answers to this problem.I recently faced this issue and found two problems in flows.

1. If you are using any kind of decision box in flow do specify the else condition also, if you wont do that it makes your variables/collection blank and updates will not be performed.
2. If you are using any kind of collection to iterate your logic on it and then updating data in the system, so before making any updates copy your current collection into a second collection.Your update(Fast update/record update) both wont work until you this.